# how to return values made in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

so I have this code:

```
import random as r
def reverse(string):
    stri = list()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        stri.insert(0, string[i])
    for j in range(len(stri)):
        print(stri[j], end="")
```

and I want to `return` the values instead of `print`ing them.
how do I make it to where the function `return`s the values and doesnt `print` them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return instead of looping through and printing:

```
def reverse(string):
    stri = list()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        stri.insert(0, string[i])
    return stri
```

If you use it like:

```
reverse("hello")
```

You'll get the array back: `['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']`

If you want a string instead you can return the joined string:

```
def reverse(string):
    stri = list()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        stri.insert(0, string[i]) 
    return "".join(stri)
```

Then the function will return 'olleh'.

If you want to use a little more of what python offers you can also do something like:

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

print(reverse("hello"))
# --> olleh
```